# How to add new row to Listview webcontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net

anyone hv any idea about adding row to listview control. iam searching the code for many days bt i find only inserting int listview bt i dnt need this my issue is if there is textchange event happens in row as per value in that textbox new rows will be created for eg if  textbox hv value two and row index is 2 after that there are other rows also then in between rows 2 new rows should be created 
In my image at row 2 no of nites are 2 if i make them 1 then new row should be inserted after that row.
if nyone cn help me i"ll be very thankful to him/her. 
[image]

Comment: Do you know anything about punctuations ?

Comment: instead of list view you can go for grid view it will be easy

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`YourListViewID.Items.Insert(index, item);`

on the event you want it in Or using with jQuery/ajax.

Comment: bt i want new row as above row not a single control can u please write sample code for this